# cannot build in release only in debug

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors, release

I have a project built in VS 2013, for some reason I cannot build in release mode only debug mode. If I build in release mode I get a bunch of errors that doesn't really seem relavant. Anyone got any suggestion on where to begin looking for errors?

Comment: Can you post the errors? It's hard to guess exactly what could go wrong without them.

Comment: Error 15 'Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.Web.UI, Version=2015.1.401.45, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4' or one of its dependencies. Invalid pointer (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004003 (E_POINTER))' 
    Error 3 Metadata file 'xxxx.dll' could not be found

Answer (score 1):

From your error I can guess that you're using an external library, either through NuGet or locally.

You have to set up the environment to use this library in both release and debug mode. That means installing it on either one through NuGet or setting up the correct include/library paths in the project settings.

Comment: Sure, but I have built in release mode for months in this project using the same external libraries without errors, this problem started today and I just cant figure it out.

Comment: Is the library inside your project folder still? Was there an update to the library that made breaking changes? Are there other errors besides that one? The question is pretty vague at this point.

Comment: The library path is valid and I have added it once more without issues. And there has not been any update made to this library. How can it build in debug mode and not release?

Comment: I'd say edit your post with more information. Add the actual error log, put information like this project is months old and it just stopped working, add important build information, etc. With more information it's easier to give an answer.

Comment: It was probably caused by errors in one of the csproj files. I was able to restore one from a backup and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was an unrelated Nuget package that had a higher .Net Framework version than my project.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, with the same error of Invalid pointer, and it turned out that **I had uninstalled Telerik from machine.**

**1. Make sure that you have Telerik installed** , on my machine it is under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Telerik\UI for ASP.NET AJAX Q3 2015\"
The file "Telerik.Web.UI.dll" is available in the Bin[nn]-folders, select the one you want (perhaps the latest version).

**2. In visual studio; if your reference to "Telerik.Web.UI" has a yellow warning triangle** it indicates that Visual Studio cannot locate the dll file.
Add new reference by browsing your Telerik Bin[nn] folder and selecting the file "Telerik.Web.UI.dll" (and repeat this for all projects using the Telerik components in your solution)